# MediaWiki Permissions

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I am trying to setup the permissions and was wondering if this is possible.

I want to have users be able to create talk and discussions pages, but not edit content pages.

Only Trusted can have the option of editing content pages.

Can this be done in MediaWiki?

I have read through the docs, and it seems for editing it is either all or nothing.

Am I missing something?

Thanks...

Comment: You mean MediaWiki? Wikimedia is the organization that develops MediaWiki and runs wikis like Wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$wgNamespaceProtection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgNamespaceProtection) lets you do this. Put something like this in your LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_MAIN] = array( 'edit-main' );
//This restricts editing in the main namespace to people in a group that has the 'edit-main' permission.

$wgGroupPermissions['trusted']['edit-main'] = true;
//This means only people in a new 'trusted' group have the 'edit-main' permission
```

Alternatively instead of 'trusted', put 'sysop', to mean sysops are the ones who also get to edit the main namespace (as well as deleting pages and other sysop permissions)

But if you *do* want a new group called 'trusted', then you would probably also want to create pages on your wiki with the following little content snippets, to make the interface describe this new 'trusted' group correctly:

- on a page called `MediaWiki:Group-trusted` put the content 'Trusted'
- on a page called `MediaWiki:Group-trusted-member` put the content 'trusted'
- on a page called `MediaWiki:Grouppage-trusted` put the content 'Project:trusted'

I'm basing this on the 'ninja' example on [Manual:User rights](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_rights)